# Remote branch is both behind and ahead of master

Tags: git, github

I used BFG Repo Cleaner as instructed [here](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/), and pushed to remote.

After that I realized that my branches are both ahead and behind by some hundred commits.
Each branch should be ahead by few most recent commits prior to using the repo cleaner. I think it created a brand new completely disjoint history.

I tried to perform a rebase master onto each branch, but there appears to be a lot of conflict files.  It's pretty much going through the history and expecting to resolve conflicts for each commit. Obviously this is very time consuming, and there's a lot of room for error.

Is there a cleaner and faster way to fix all these local branches to be ahead of master by recent commits only?

Answer (score 3):

> I think it created a brand new completely disjoint history.

Yes, that is what BFG does: it rewrites the history in order to purge the commits from certain (big) files.

If you have forced push to the remote, you need to fetch and reset your local branch to the new remote one (make sure you don't have local modifications in progress).

```
git fetch
git branch tmp
git reset --hard origin/myBranch
```

If you have in `tmp` a few new commits, [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) them on top of your reset branch

Then you can resume making new commits from that new state.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your suggested approach, but there is nothing to push after reset --hard. Maybe I failed to explain that the branches are already ahead and behind of master on remote, and the local versions are in correct state relative to their remote. Maybe this screenshot clarifies my issue: http://prntscr.com/fus03h
Basically these branches should be ahead by 11, 3 and 11 commits, not 208, 200, and 208. Is there a way to reset these?

Comment: @seemvision there is nothing to push after `reset --hard`: that is expected. If you have local commits, you need to cherry-pick them first from `tmp` (the old branch) on the new state of the branch, and then push.